# How to make a content DIV move up to the top of a viewable area of a monitor?

Tags: css, html

Thank you in advance with your advise.

I have a `position:fixed` navigation `div` at the top. I want that to scroll down and up (remain at the top of the webpage) when the user moves throughout the page. I have figured that part out.

However, I have a content `div` `position:absolute` that is not in the viewable area of the webpage. I have a link in my navigation `div` and I want it to interact with the content `div` so when the user clicks on that link, the content `div` moves (scrolls) up to the top of the webpage.

I cannot figure out the CSS to do this... Again thank you for the help.

Comment: If you can't attach an image, please send a link to the file and provide your HTML code. Thanks.

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5939938#5939938